# return the first n elements of a k sized array in O(1) time

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Given an array of size k, with the first n elements assigned a non-null reference, how would I go about returning an array with only the first n elements of size n in Java?

Obviously you could could do a deep copy by creating a new k sized array and then iterate though the initial one n times, transferring the elements at each iteration but then that would be an O(n) operation.

What I thought may be possible from my understanding of how arrays are stored in memory would be to simply change the length property of the array from k to n and then returning the reference of the initial array.

As a pseudo method:

```
public Foo[] head(Foo[] arr, int n) {
    arr.length = n;
    return arr;
}
```

I was wondering if anything can be done to produce this as a constant time operation but I fear that it may be impossible as Java does not support anything like pointer arithmetic.

If this is impossible, what would be the quickest way of providing the same result?

Comment: You can't do this in O(1) time.  The length of arrays in Java cannot be changed, so you need to make a new one.  Jarrod's answer provides details on how to do this properly.

Comment: @Math Thanks, was just wondering if it's doable any faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must work with raw arrays and not `ArrayList` then `Arrays` has what you need. If you look at the source code, these are the absolutely best ways to get a copy of an array. They do have a good bit of defensive programming because the `System.arraycopy()` method throws lots of unchecked exceptions if you feed it illogical parameters.

You can use either [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-T:A-int-) which will copy from the first to `Nth` element to the new shorter array.

```
public static <T> T[] copyOf(T[] original, int newLength)
```

> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with nulls (if
>   necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all indices that
>   are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will
>   contain identical values. For any indices that are valid in the copy
>   but not the original, the copy will contain null. Such indices will
>   exist if and only if the specified length is greater than that of the
>   original array. The resulting array is of exactly the same class as
>   the original array.

```
2770
2771    public static <T,U> T[] More ...copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
2772        T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
2773            ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
2774            : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
2775        System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
2776                         Math.min(original.length, newLength));
2777        return copy;
2778    }
```

or `Arrays.copyOfRange()` will also do the trick:

```
public static <T> T[] copyOfRange(T[] original, int from, int to)
```

> Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array.
>   The initial index of the range (from) must lie between zero and
>   original.length, inclusive. The value at original[from] is placed into
>   the initial element of the copy (unless from == original.length or
>   from == to). Values from subsequent elements in the original array are
>   placed into subsequent elements in the copy. The final index of the
>   range (to), which must be greater than or equal to from, may be
>   greater than original.length, in which case null is placed in all
>   elements of the copy whose index is greater than or equal to
>   original.length - from. The length of the returned array will be to -
>   from. The resulting array is of exactly the same class as the original
>   array.

```
3035    public static <T,U> T[] More ...copyOfRange(U[] original, int from, int to, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
3036        int newLength = to - from;
3037        if (newLength < 0)
3038            throw new IllegalArgumentException(from + " > " + to);
3039        T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
3040            ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
3041            : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
3042        System.arraycopy(original, from, copy, 0,
3043                         Math.min(original.length - from, newLength));
3044        return copy;
3045    }
```

As you can see, both of these are just wrapper functions over `System.arraycopy` with defensive logic that what you are trying to do is valid.

[`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) is the absolute fastest way to copy arrays.

Comment: Thanks. Both of the utility functions use System.arraycopy which is linear with regards to the new array size. Is constant time an impossibility in this case?

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Constant time is impossible.  This is as good as it gets.

Comment: the only way you can get what you want is to use something like the `Iterators.filter(iterable,Predicate)` function in Guava. They are lazy and only process items as they are accessed. But they are not raw arrays, this is the only way to efficiently ( time and space ) get a sub-array and keep it a raw array.

Comment: Constant time is not impossible, it's just impossible given your limits. If you want constant time, just pass that value of n around with the array and know that your array's first n elements matter. But given his requirements that it stay an array you *must* copy the n elements so you're screwed. I provided an O(1) solution, as you can provide a backed subList() of a backed Array.asList() but it was the wrong type. But both of those things just wrap the data and save the value of n for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [sublist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)). (List rather than array)

But, the point is always the same. Save the value of n and the array. You're already done. You can use those for the same thing you'd use a different fake array that pretends to be a different size for, just pretend the array is size n, and  use the array.

Though if you must,

```
List<MyClass> subArray = Arrays.asList(array).subList(index, index2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of List.subList() but unfortunately, I'm restricted to returning an array at the end of the method. :/

Comment: Then there isn't one. Just use Array.CopyOf(n), it's the only reasonable solution. And the internal copy routine is really fast. As far as things go, it's the fastest way to move data with System.arrayCopy() which is what copyof uses internally.